GTA San Andreas game is not working on my Honor 8C phone!
I am able to access the game homepage, but it crashes during the game loading time. I couldn't find a solution on YouTube either....
Processor - Qualcomm Snapdragon 632
Variant - 4GB Ram & 32GB Storage
OS - Android 9.0 Pie.
Problem - There isn't any kind of error popup when I start the game. The loading screen appears, but after it loads halfway, it gets stuck for 10 to 15 seconds, then shows a black screen and throws me out to the phone's home screen.
I have tried to find a solution on YouTube, but there is no solution. In fact, of this phone, lower and upper versions game is working. just only problem with HONOR 8C..

Please edit to include more relevant info, i.e. Android OS version, device RAM, error message on crash, etc.

Are you able to get a logcat log, so that we have a specific error message that might cause the app to crash? Without it, we'd pretty much just need to guess.

NO let me explain you again look,


I open the game ( now i am at the game home page where is Load game, start new game, settings, and credits options)


Then i click on load game


Game is loading


Suddenly Everyhitng is black then i am redirect to my phone home screen


Understood?

It's obviously an issue with the app causing a crash for whatever reason, and this reason (usually) is caught in logcat. Without any other information, it's impossible to tell what would cause the crash. Does starting a new game work OK? If so, it's likely that the save is corrupted and is causing the app to crash.

Whwn i downloaded and started the game for the first time, but it kept crashing. Searching for solutions on YouTube, I came across a suggestion to load a save game. I downloaded a save file and placed it in the data folder. The game now shows a "load game" option, but unfortunately, this solution isn't working either......

Another thing that just occurred to me, are you trying to install the Definitive Edition from the Play Store or Netflix, or the previous (non-Definitive Edition) version from the Play Store?

I am talking about the regular game, not the Definitive Edition. The APK name is 'Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas.......
